# Error when upgrading Magento using composer (2.2.1 to 2.2.5)

Tags: magento2

When trying to upgrade the Magento version from 2.2.1 to 2.2.5 using composer, the following error occurs during the upgrade:

> Module 'Magento_Sales':Upgrading data. Requested product doesn't exist

Any advice or experience regarding the resolution of this error would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like there is a good chance this is related to your product data (see https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Requested-product-doesn-t-exist-Magento-2-1-3/m-p/58108/highlight/true#M1788 ), which suggests that your query is probably more suited to the Magenta support forums than stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Check products in the database.

please check whether the product id is there in DB or not. Based on that issue can be traced. –

Comment: Exactly what I have to check in Products. All products have SKU.